# Brew on MacOs for PhP version

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

i need to install Homebrew on MacOs to upgrade my php version with :

```
-
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

but when i try to install to install homebrew i don't see some change i try this :

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

from homebrew doc site but when i use that i dont see where brew was instal and zhs says again that brew is not found so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew is normally installed in `/usr/local` (or if you're using an M1 Mac, `/opt/homebrew`).

Try running `/usr/local/bin/brew` or `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew`. If neither of those work, there was most likely a failure during the installation of Homebrew. What was the output you got when you ran the install command?

Comment: I dont fint it in usr/bin/local when i started the instalation its says that the script explains what it will do and then pauses before it does it. But when i run the cmd for installation its says that i need to press return to continue but it dosnt work : 
```Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
XXXXX@MacBook-Air-XXXXXX ~ %  ```

Comment: J'ai trouvé j'inversais la touche return j'appuyais sur retour arrière au lieu d'entrée persuadé par ma connerie merci :)